# Best method of store & address to set of texts

Tags: data-structures, data-storage

I have some texts from different authors with different address system in each text. For example it could be:

- chapter & subchapter
- page & column
- page & starter words
- chapter & verse

And so on. What is the best method to store that texts and access its content whits that address system? For example, one text has link to another text, chapter 4 subchapter 3.
As for now, I realized next system:
I have folder for each author, which has folders for each book. If that book have chapters - each chapter stored in separate file (as for now I don't want to keep it in files for simplify store and editing), if not - all book is stored in one file. All other addresses (pages, starter words for paragraphs) are sored as tags (maybe it should be xml file)

When I want to access text by api, I request `Link` object from `Storage`, fill it with addresses and send it to `Storage` back. That system is needed, because only `Storage` knows how text are stored. And if I want to change storage system to another (for example store each book as one file) I should change only `Link` realization without changing another code.